# How to stop GitLab from evaluating $ inside variable value?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am passing `GitLab` variable while running CI/CD pipeline as below.

```
type - variable
key - password
value - {"a": "abc$def@pqr"}
```

I am reading it in some `GitLab` pipeline stage as below.

```
echo $password
```

It is showing as below.

```
{"a":"abc@pqr"}
```

But I want it to show as below.

```
{"a":"abc$def@pqr"}
```

I don't want it to evaluate `$def` as blank

**Note:**

- I tried with \ escaping and with single quotes too.
- I need this to be in `json` kind of format itself for further use.

Comment: You tried `abc\$def@pqr`?

Comment: Yes that's still behaving the same i.e. as {"a": "abc\@pqr"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine on using double $$ instead of single $